# Display fetched movie title from API in order history not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I've created a JavaScript program in which a user can enter (a part of) a movie in a textbox to fetch movie information through the [OMDB](https://www.omdbapi.com) API. After that the user can order tickets for that particular movie. The user information is being kept in an order history.

I have an issue however. In the order history it shows the movie name the way the user typed it, instead of showing the movie as being found by the API. For example:

I am looking for the movie "The Passion of the Christ". I type "The Passion of the":

[image]

The movie the OMDB API does come up with the correct movie, but how do I integrate this in a variable and show it in my order list?

I've been fiddling with my code but can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
"use strict";
const orderHistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Order-History")) || [];
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

function init() {
  hookupEventHandlers();
  showOrderHistory();
}

function hookupEventHandlers() {
  document.getElementById("Find-Movie").addEventListener("click", fetchMoviePoster); //When clicking "find movie" button, execute function "Fetchmovieposter"
  document.getElementById("Place-Order").addEventListener("click", function(e) { // When clicking "place order" button, execute functions "preventdefault", "processform", "Showorderhistory"
    e.preventDefault();
    processForm();
    showOrderHistory();
  });
}

function fetchMoviePoster() { //collecting movie title requested by user, create apiURL based on requested movie and the API key which we retrieved from the OMDB API
  const movieTitle = document.querySelector("#Movie-Title").value;
  const apiKey = "c3b11b36";
  const apiUrl = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${movieTitle}&apikey=${apiKey}`;

  fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const posterElement = document.querySelector("#Movie-Poster");
      const posterSection = document.querySelector("#Poster-Section");
      const orderformSection = document.querySelector("#Order-Form");
      const movieTitleItself = document.querySelector(".Movie-Title");
      if (movieTitle == "") { // if not movie title is entered by user, an error pops up. Further Execution of script stops.
        alert("Please enter a movie title!");
        return false;
      }
      posterElement.src = data.Poster;
      posterSection.style.display = "block";
      orderformSection.style.display = "block";
      movieTitleItself.textContent = data.Title;
    })
}

function processForm(e) { // The data we need to collect when the form is processed. This data gets added to the order history.
  const user = document.querySelector("#User");
  const movieTitle = document.querySelector("#Movie-Title");
  const amountOfTickets = document.querySelector("#Ticket-Amount");
  const email = document.querySelector("#Email");
  addOrderToHistory(user, email, movieTitle, amountOfTickets);
}

function addOrderToHistory(userinput, emailinput, movieTitle, amountOfTicketsinput) {

  const user = userinput.value;
  const movieTitleItself = movieTitle.value
  const amountOfTickets = amountOfTicketsinput.value;
  const email = emailinput.value;

  const order = { //the order consists of the entered information from the user
    user,
    email,
    movieTitleItself,
    amountOfTickets,
  };
  const form = document.querySelector("form"); // bunch of validation checks. If one of the fields is empty, or more than 8 tickets are ordered, errors pops up and execution stops.
  if (!user || !amountOfTickets || !email || (!form.checkValidity())) {
    alert("Please fill in all required fields and order more than 1 but less than 9 tickets. Make sure you entered a valid email-address");
    return false;
  }
  displayThankYouMessage(); // User sees thank you message if validation rules are met. The order gets pushed to localstorage!
  orderHistory.push(order);
  localStorage.setItem("Order-History", JSON.stringify(orderHistory));

}

function displayThankYouMessage() { // function which shows the thank you message if validation rules are met.
  const thankYouSection = document.querySelector("#Thank-You");
  thankYouSection.style.display = "block";
}

function showOrderHistory() { // the creation of the order history. The elements get added as an ul with li's per order 
  const orderhistory = document.querySelector("#Order-History");
  const ul = document.querySelector("#orderList");

  ul.innerHTML = ""; // Clear the list before populating

  orderHistory.forEach((order, index) => {
    const listItem = document.createElement("li");

    listItem.innerHTML = `${order.movieTitleItself}<br> <a href="mailto:${order.email}">${order.user}</a> (${order.amountOfTickets} ticket(s))`; // show the relevant information and add the ability to mail the user via the mailto: capability.
    ul.appendChild(listItem); // add each li to each ul
    const lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
    ul.appendChild(lineBreak); // create a br after each order, to keep oversight
  });

  orderhistory.style.display = "block"; // Show the order history section
}
// the end!
```

Comment: Why doesn't `movieTitleItself.textContent = data.Title;` do what you want? You said the API returns the full title.

Comment: BTW, you should check for an empty `movieTitle` *before* you make the API call, not after.